# given a push sequence , find all possible pop sequences

Tags: stack, depth-first-search, backtracking

e.g. the push sequence is : `1,2,3`,all possible pop sequences are as follow:

- `1,2,3`
- `1,3,2`
- `2,1,3`
- `2,3,1`
- `3,2,1`

I found an algorithm on the internet,the (Java) code is :

```java
    public static void getAllPopSeq(List<Integer> pushSeq, int n, Deque<Integer> stack, List<Integer> popSeq, List<List<Integer>> res) {

        if (n == pushSeq.size() && stack.isEmpty()) {
            res.add(popSeq);
            return;
        } else {
            Deque<Integer> aux1 = new LinkedList<>(stack);
            Deque<Integer> aux2 = new LinkedList<>(stack);
            if (n < pushSeq.size()) {
                aux1.push(pushSeq.get(n));
                getAllPopSeq(pushSeq, n + 1, aux1, new ArrayList<>(popSeq), res);
            }
            if (!aux2.isEmpty()) {
                popSeq.add(aux2.pop());
                getAllPopSeq(pushSeq, n, aux2, new ArrayList<>(popSeq), res);
            }
        }
    }
```

But it's really hard for me to understand this algorithm,It'll be really helpful if someone can explian it for me.

or you have another solution,you can post it here.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I refactor a more clear to understand version, correct me if I'm wrong.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    // Time Complexity: O(n) ???
    // Space Complexity: O(result size)
    private List<List<Integer>> getAllPopSeq(List<Integer> pushSeq) {
        // recursive
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Integer> seq = new ArrayList<>();
        Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        dfs(pushSeq, 0, stack, seq, res);
        return res;
    }

    private void dfs(List<Integer> pushSeq, int index, Deque<Integer> stack, List<Integer> seq,
                     List<List<Integer>> res) {
        // if current index reach the end of the push seq && stack is empty
        if (index == pushSeq.size() && stack.isEmpty()) {
            // add this sequence into the result list
            res.add(seq);
            return;
        }
        // now we have 2 choices:
        // 1. push the current element into the stack
        // 2. pop the top element in the stack
        // we need to consider all possible sequences
        // push
        if (index < pushSeq.size()) {
            Deque<Integer> stack1 = new ArrayDeque<>(stack);
            stack1.push(pushSeq.get(index));
            dfs(pushSeq, index + 1, stack1, new ArrayList<>(seq), res);
        }
        // pop
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            Deque<Integer> stack2 = new ArrayDeque<>(stack);
            seq.add(stack2.pop());
            dfs(pushSeq, index, stack2, new ArrayList<>(seq), res);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution s = new Solution();
        List<Integer> pushSeq = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        List<List<Integer>> allPopSeq = s.getAllPopSeq(pushSeq);
        System.out.println(allPopSeq);
    }
}
```